# How to customize an Axapta report "SysReportAuto" ?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I know how to modify a 'physical' report with a defined name, and called from a button. But, in Axapta there are some reports called from the print button in the toolbar. 
How can one modify a system report like 'sysreportauto'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields shown in the auto report comes from the [AutoReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa678005%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) field group on the table.

You can, as a user, change the auto report, by clicking Edit\New, then choose the fields you would like to see.

You can also specify group totals in Select\Sorting, and grand totals in Select\Print options.